How can I close the existing Windows Service when updating it via MSIX?
I have an application running as a Windows Service and packaged as MSIX.
When I update the MSIX package with a new version, if I manually stop the existing service before updating the update goes smoothly, but if I don't stop the existing service the new instance starts running alongside the old one, causing conflicts.
Is there a way to configure the appxmanifest so that the installer closes the pre-existing service if it is already running before performing the update? Or is there another recommended way?
